# Integrating cocos2d in UIKit app

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having some troubles integrating a cocos2d scene inside a tab of an existing app.
I developed the scene using the Xcode template that comes with cocos2d and it works fine, but when I try to load the same scene on the existing app all that comes out is a black screen.

Here's the code I run when I load the UIViewController linked to the tab

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
        director = [CCDirector sharedDirector]; //declared in the header file
        //declared in the header file, sized as whole screen minus the tab bar
        coolview = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320,321) pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB56 depthFormat:0 preserveBackbuffer:NO sharegroup:nil multiSampling:NO numberOfSamples:0]; 
        [director setView:coolview];
        [self setView:coolview];
        [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
        [director setDelegate:self];
        [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
        [director runWithScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];
        }
```

Any idea why I should get a black screen? What am I missing?

The code in the HelloWorld layer is executed, the objects are instantiated but it just seems like they don't get rendered.

I get the following feedback also:

```
OpenGL error 0x0501 in -[CCShaderCache loadDefaultShaders] 174
OpenGL error 0x0501 in -[CCTextureAtlas initVAO] 167
OpenGL error 0x0501 in -[CCDirector setView:] 308
OpenGL error 0x0501 in -[CCTextureAtlas initVAO] 167
```

but I haven't been able to find the meaning of the error codes.
I'm using cocos2d version 2.

Thanks in advance for any help
Luca

A little update: this problem does not happen with version 1.0.1, replacing CCGLView with EAGLView.
So I'll assume this might be a little bug of this release.

Unfortunately I can't switch to 1.0.1 because I need some features of box2d v2.2 that comes only with cocos2d v2.0.
I'm trying to make box2d v2.2 work with cocos v1.0.1 but it's getting pretty ugly!

Anyone knows how I could fix it in 2.0 or at least point me in the right direction? Where could the problem be? In CCDirector or CCGLView?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: The one thing that looks fishy in your code is the line "[director runWithScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];"  CCLayer doesn't have a scene property.  Why would you put a CCScene object inside a layer?  Do you actually have anything in your scene to render?  I tried your code in a test app and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have all the Cocos2D initialisation code as well. Cocos2D creates an openGL rendering context which is then drawn to to display the sprites. If you look at the template app that comes with cocos, in the AppDelegate, there is a load of initialisation stuff.

I'm not even sure if it is possible (or if it is, if it is easy) to incorporate a cocos2d scene into an existing iOS app.

Comment: It definitely is possible to incorporate a cocos2d scene into an existing iOS (or OS X) app. You have to pull in the cocos2d source files, of course.

Answer (score 0):

After you'll done with all initialization stuff, Nick Bull talking about, you'll need to note one thing: cocos2d draws on his own CCLayer. But I think this layer, and the layer, wich is in all UIView sublasses - is the same things. If you'll fine the way to replase them, or link somehow, you'll can do any cocos2d staff in your views. This should be starting point for you, good luck.

Comment: I tried what Nick Bull said, copying and pasting everything from the appdelegate to the viewDidLoad, but nothing changed.
Can you elaborate what you suggested? It seems interesting but I don't understand well. Can you tell me more please?

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell much more: I never tried to do what you are doing, this is only my guess. You see, cocos2d uses many features from UIKit, not in clean form: many of them (or, may be, all?) subclassed from UIKit. MAY BE, CCLayer sublassed too. If it is, you can try to replace layer from UIView with CCLayer from cocos2d. I just hope that layer from UIView is not protected or something...